# My activity is lag, it it because of the code?

Tags: dart, flutter

```
class _DaftarMuridState extends State<DaftarMurid> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Column(
         children: <Widget>[
           new Flexible(
             child: new FirebaseAnimatedList(//new
               query: db.reference().child("Murid"),
               sort: (a, b) => a.key.compareTo(b.key),                
               padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),                      
               itemBuilder: (_, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, Animation<double> animations,x){
                 return new DaftarMuridView(
                   snapshot: dataSnapshot,
                   animation: animations,
                 );//new
               }
             ),
           ),
         ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DaftarMuridViewState extends State<DaftarMuridView>{
  DaftarMuridViewState({this.snapshot, this.animation});
  final DataSnapshot snapshot;
  final Animation animation;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    String fotoUrl = snapshot.value['Foto'];
    String ig = snapshot.value['Instagram'];
    hash.putIfAbsent(snapshot.value['Nama'], () => false);
    bool expanded = hash[snapshot.value['Nama']];
    var expansionPanel = new ExpansionPanelList(
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
          setState(() {
            hash.remove(snapshot.value['Nama']);
            hash.putIfAbsent(snapshot.value['Nama'], () => !isExpanded);
            expanded = !expanded;
          });
      },
      children: [new ExpansionPanel(headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
      return new ListTile(
          leading: const Icon(Icons.school),
          title: new Text(
            snapshot.value['Nama'],
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            style: new TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ));
      },
        body: new ListView(
            physics:  const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            children: <Widget>[
              new CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: fotoUrl == null?"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1tkqO59S9jiWpkzHQNJRKLuCGYIn5kK_v":fotoUrl,
                placeholder: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                errorWidget: new CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1tkqO59S9jiWpkzHQNJRKLuCGYIn5kK_v"),
                fadeOutDuration: new Duration(seconds: 1),
                fadeInDuration: new Duration(seconds: 1),
                height: size.height / 2.0,
                width: size.width / 2.0,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
              ),
              new ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.today),
                title: const Text('Tanggal Lahir'),
                subtitle: new Text(snapshot.value['Tanggal Lahir']),
              ),
              new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ig != null ?
                    new FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () => _instagram(ig),
                    child: new CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: "http://diylogodesigns.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Instagram-logo-png-icon.png", width: size.width / 4.0, height: size.height / 4.0, ),
                    )
                  : new Container(),
                ],
              ),
            ],
        ),
        isExpanded: expanded)],
    );
    return new SizeTransition(
        sizeFactor: new CurvedAnimation(
            parent: animation, curve: Curves.easeOut),
      axisAlignment: 0.0,
      child: expansionPanel,
    );
  }
}
```

is my code not efficient? the process is Get Data from Firebase -> Store it to list view

it's a bit lag when open the activity, maybe because getting the data. But is there a solution for make it doesn't lag?

I cut some code that isn't important.

Comment: Why would you load images like a generic black face and an instagram logo from a web url? You can add them as assets in your project and load them way quicker. Also, loading an 'error' image from the web doesn't make sense, as the user might not be able to connect to that server, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks man, i will make it load from assets

Answer (score 0):

Use Futures to perform time consuming operations, so it will not freeze the UI.
https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures

Comment: i forgot to change the title, i think it doesn't need future. Almost all code is building widget